# Spring boot mixed form login and oauth2 Google login don't work when deploying the code in Google Cloud

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-app-engine, spring-security

I have a Spring Boot web application with two types of authentication configurations. One is form login for admin and the other is OAuth2 using Google account.

This works fine when I run it locally on Eclipse. It also works fine when I run the same using `./mvnw spring-boot:run` on cloud-shell. But when I deploy the application to Google App engine or Google Run, the form login stop working. The form login doesn't show up and the the webpage secured for admin is accessible to anyone. The Google OAuth2 login always works fine.

Here is the code for security config.

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
// Spring boot security configuration
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public static PasswordEncoder encoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    // Admin credential configuration
    @Configuration
    @Order(1)
    public static class AdminConfigurationAdapter {
        @Bean
        public UserDetailsService userDetailsServiceAdmin() {
            UserDetails user = User
                    .withUsername("admin")
                    .password(encoder().encode("adminPass"))
                    .roles("ADMIN")
                    .build();
            return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(user);
        }

        @Bean
        public SecurityFilterChain filterChainAdmin(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                .antMatcher("/admin*")
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .anyRequest().hasRole("ADMIN")
                    // log in
                    .and()
                .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/loginAdmin")
                    .loginProcessingUrl("/admin_login")
                    .failureUrl("/loginAdmin?error=loginError")
                    .defaultSuccessUrl("/admin_view")
                    // logout
                    .and()
                .logout()
                    .logoutUrl("/admin_logout")
                    .logoutSuccessUrl("/welcome")
                    .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                    .and()
                .exceptionHandling()
                    .accessDeniedPage("/403")
                    .and()
                .csrf().disable();

            return http.build();
        }
    }

    // Google account oauth2 login configuration
    @Order(2)
    @Configuration
    public static class ApplicantConfiguration {
        @Bean
        public SecurityFilterChain filterChainApplicant(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/applicant*").authenticated()
                    .and()
                .oauth2Login()
                    .and()
                .logout()
                    .logoutSuccessUrl("/welcome")
                    .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                    .and()
                .exceptionHandling()
                    .accessDeniedPage("/403");
            return http.build();
        }
    }
}
```

I found that if I create two different form login using different user/passwd, it works fine in Google Cloud App engine. Only the case that the form login mixed with Google OAuth2 login doesn't work.

Here are the Spring Security debug logs for comparing. When running on Google Cloud APP, it says "Authorized public object filter invocation [GET /admin_view]". When running locally, it says "Redirecting to http://localhost:8080/loginAdmin". I just couldn't figure out why.

**The logs for the working one on localhost:8080**

```
2022-12-29 22:05:08.768 DEBUG 92679 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /admin_view

2022-12-29 22:05:08.768 DEBUG 92679 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Set SecurityContextHolder to empty SecurityContext

2022-12-29 22:05:08.768 DEBUG 92679 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext

2022-12-29 22:05:08.768 DEBUG 92679 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.w.session.SessionManagementFilter  : Request requested invalid session id 0C1EB7E035C74BC01E7F8D1E706683FC

2022-12-29 22:05:08.776 DEBUG 92679 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Failed to authorize filter invocation [GET /admin_view] with attributes [hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')]

2022-12-29 22:05:08.798 DEBUG 92679 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache        : Saved request http://localhost:8080/admin_view to session

2022-12-29 22:05:08.799 DEBUG 92679 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy        : Redirecting to http://localhost:8080/loginAdmin
```

**The logs for the application running on Google App engine.**

```
2022-12-30 03:07:15 default[20221230t020608]  2022-12-30 03:07:15.991 DEBUG 11 --- [0.0-8081-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /admin_view

2022-12-30 03:07:15 default[20221230t020608]  2022-12-30 03:07:15.992 DEBUG 11 --- [0.0-8081-exec-2] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Set SecurityContextHolder to empty SecurityContext

2022-12-30 03:07:15 default[20221230t020608]  2022-12-30 03:07:15.992 DEBUG 11 --- [0.0-8081-exec-2] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext

2022-12-30 03:07:15 default[20221230t020608]  2022-12-30 03:07:15.992 DEBUG 11 --- [0.0-8081-exec-2] o.s.s.w.session.SessionManagementFilter  : Request requested invalid session id A7635E4C3457927648904B5BCAC69E7C

2022-12-30 03:07:15 default[20221230t020608]  2022-12-30 03:07:15.992 DEBUG 11 --- [0.0-8081-exec-2] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Authorized public object filter invocation [GET /admin_view]

2022-12-30 03:07:15 default[20221230t020608]  2022-12-30 03:07:15.993 DEBUG 11 --- [0.0-8081-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Secured GET /admin_view
```

Comment: For the local test, I use http://localhost:8080. For Google cloud test, I use http://eomclubregistrationweb.ue.r.appspot.com which is generated by Google cloud. I don't know if there is any reverse proxy or not.

Comment: I am sure I am running the same Spring application code on Google. The pom.xml has some extra configuration for Google. I use Java 17 locally while Google requires to use Java 11. I added more debug logs above. Please take a look. It looks like Ant [pattern='/admin*'] is missing in the log on Google.

Comment: All your comments should be added to the question. Edit and rewite if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue is related to the order of the security config applied to the Spring security framework.

When running the code using localhost:8080, the admin security config is applied first and the Google oauth2 is applied later. I noticed this from the Spring security debug log. However, when running the same code on google cloud, the order of processing the security config is reversed. I don't know why. Once the google oauth2 is configured first, the admin form login is configured later, I start to see the issue.

So, a workaround fix is available. I tried to reverse the security config order in the code for my google cloud version. This did fix the issue. I was able to see the admin form login as well as Google oauth2 login.

It looks like the "@Order" doesn't work as expected. The actual order of processing the security config is determined by the class name alphabetically.